# What is the direction of force acting on a current carrying conductor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electric-current, magnetic-moment

Let magnetic field be from left to right side of the screen and current be flowing from top to bottom part of the screen. Then the force acting on the conductor is out of the screen (towards the viewer), by Fleming's left hand rule. 
But by the formula, I(L x B), the direction of force is into the screen. This is because the direction of length vector is in the direction of velocity of charged body (electrons, in this case) which is opposite to the direction of current.

So what is the explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused here. The formula for the force acting on a current carrying conductor is $$\mathbf F=l(\mathbf I\times \mathbf B)$$

where $\mathbf F$ is the force, $l$ is the length (which is a scalar value), $\mathbf I$ is the current and $\mathbf B$ is the magnetic field strength. This formula works.

When physicists talk about current, they are referring to **conventional current**. This is opposite to the direction of flow of electrons. The direction of $\mathbf I$ is the direction of movement of positive charge.

Comment: Now that I searched in Google, I found that there are different versions of this formula, with some considering length and others considering current as vectors. Please clarify.

Comment: @Zam Think about it: does length have a direction? Length is simply the distance of conductor that is in the magnetic field. Current is a vector quantity because the charge flows in a certain direction.

Comment: @Zam I just searched the internet and was surprised to see length as a vector quantity. Those formulae probably still work - however, for me, it is more intuitive to think of length as a scalar and current as a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:

> the direction of length vector is in the direction of velocity of charged body (electrons, in this case) which is opposite to the direction of current.

In the formula $\textbf F=I(\textbf l\times \textbf B)$, we take the direction of $\textbf l$ to be the direction of current flow and that's why the direction of force would be out of the screen only.

I would also like to point out that neither current nor length is a vector, but since we are considering a straight wire we can assign a direction to either so as to come up with a formula for force. So, the formula could also have been $\textbf F=l(\textbf I \times \textbf B)$.